# Change multiple classes on various elements in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a basic quiz app whereby after the user selects an answer, they press the 'check' button and if the selected answer is correct, it is highlighted green while the other answers are highlighted red. Likewise when the wrong answer is selected, the selected answer is red while the correct answer is highlighted green.

Currently my code would either show all answers as green if correct or all answers red if incorrect. Therefore how can achieve the desired result described above?

```
<script>
  let questionIndex = 0
  let selectedAnswer
  let correct
  let incorrect

  const quiz = [
    {
      question: 'What is the capital of France?',
      correct_answer: 'Paris',
      answers: ['Berlin', 'London', 'Madrid', 'Paris'],
    }
  ]

  const currentQuestion = quiz[questionIndex]
  const correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correct_answer

  const checkAnswer = () => {

    if (selectedAnswer  == correctAnswer) {
      correct = true
    }
        else {
            incorrect = true
        }

    }

</script>

<style>

  .correct {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }

  .incorrect {
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>

<main>
  <h3>{quiz[questionIndex].question}</h3>

    <label class:correct class:incorrect>
                <input
                type="radio"
                bind:group={selectedAnswer}
                value={quiz[questionIndex].answers[0]} />
            {quiz[questionIndex].answers[0]}
        </label>
    
    <label class:correct class:incorrect>
                <input
                type="radio"
                bind:group={selectedAnswer}
                value={quiz[questionIndex].answers[1]} />
            {quiz[questionIndex].answers[1]}
      </label>

    <label class:correct class:incorrect>
                <input
                type="radio"
                bind:group={selectedAnswer}
                value={quiz[questionIndex].answers[2]} />
            {quiz[questionIndex].answers[2]}
      </label>

    <label class:correct class:incorrect>
                <input
                type="radio"
                bind:group={selectedAnswer}
                value={quiz[questionIndex].answers[3]} />
            {quiz[questionIndex].answers[3]}
      </label>

  <button on:click={checkAnswer}>Check</button>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is repetitive, so make it a loop to save some work.

Now, for each item, what we want is the following:

- class `correct` if the button has been clicked, and the item is the right answer
- class `incorrect` if the button has been clicked and (a) the answer is correct and the item is not the right answer, or (b) the answer is not correct and the item is not the selected answer

This translate to the following condition for the `correct` class:

```js
answered && value === correctAnswer
```

And for the incorrect class, the following hairy condition (but, to be honest, I think your requirements are a bit weird, and that contributes to the complexity of the solution):

```js
answered && (
  (correct && value !== correctAnswer) 
  || (!correct && value === selectedAnswer)
)
```

So, translated in code, this gives us something like this:

```html
<script>
  const questionIndex = 0

  let selectedAnswer
  let answered = false

  const quiz = [
    {
      question: 'What is the capital of France?',
      correct_answer: 'Paris',
      answers: ['Berlin', 'London', 'Madrid', 'Paris'],
    },
  ]

  // make this reactive!
  $: currentQuestion = quiz[questionIndex]
  $: correctAnswer = currentQuestion.correct_answer

  $: correct = selectedAnswer === correctAnswer

  const checkAnswer = () => {
    answered = true
  }

  const reset = () => {
    answered = false
  }
</script>

<main>
  <h3>{quiz[questionIndex].question}</h3>

  {#each quiz[questionIndex].answers as value}
    <label
      class:correct={answered && value === correctAnswer}
      class:incorrect={answered && ((correct && value !== correctAnswer) || (!correct && value === selectedAnswer))}>
      <input type="radio" bind:group={selectedAnswer} {value} />
      {value}
    </label>
  {/each}

  <button on:click={checkAnswer}>Check</button>
  <button on:click={reset}>Reset</button>

</main>

<style>
  .correct {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  .incorrect {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Nice Solution! Are the requirements really that weird? I thought it was the kind of expected behaviour of a quiz app, to get visual feedback to see if an answer is right or wrong.

Comment: Yes, the general idea is nice and somewhat classic. What I find more surprising is specifically making all other answers red when you have the correct answer. I think I would only highlight the selected answer, green or red depending on correctness. If I also want to show the right answer, I would also highlight the correct one in green. But just that. This would simplify the "incorrect" condition a little bit, hence my comment ;)